# Can't log in; always return to prompt

Tags: login, loop-device

How do I solve this login loop? Every time I have given the correct password, but my account is not opening. Every time it comes back to my login prompt. Crashes back to the login screen.

Comment: Crash back to login screen

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark and up-arrow icons, just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

If you've been starting graphic applications from the terminal using `sudo`, that's what probably caused your problem. Always use `sudo -H`.

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:

  - `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` # remount the disk as rw

  - `cd /home/your_username` # change directory

  - `ls -al .*thority*` # list some files

You should see something like this...

```
-rw------- 1 your_username your_username 407910 Nov  2 08:56 .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 your_username your_username     58 Jun 23  2017 .Xauthority
```

If it DOES NOT show `-rw-------` then...

- `sudo chmod 600 .*thority*` # change file protection

If it DOES SHOW `root root` then...

- `sudo chown your_username:your_username .*thority*` # change file ownership
- `reboot` # reboot the computer

Reboot and see if you can log in.